# how to find the datemodified in java using filehandling

Tags: java, performance, automation, file-handling

kindly help me how to get the datemodified of list of files present in the particular folder and get the datemodified values of that and paste the same in another XL sheet using java and file handling so that i can try for an automation of the same.

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to provide you with code to do all of those those things.  That's not the way StackOverflow works.  This is a Q&A site ... not a site where people do your programming for free.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [lastModified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) method of file object like:

```
File file = new File("<file path>");
System.out.println(new Date(file.lastModified()));//lastModified will return you time in milli second since 1st Jan 1970 and by wrapping long into date you get proper date object.

Output:
Sun Sep 21 01:36:49 IST 2014
```